# How can I sort file explorer by date in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, file

In a WPF application, I did open the file explorer.
I use this code.

```
string filePath = DataManager.OptionData.Workspace;  
Process.Start(filePath);
```

However, I want to sort file explorer by date in code.

I want to show the users an file explorer **window** that is sorted by date.
Is it possible?

---

[image]

Comment: You're probably looking for `System.IO.FileInfo`

Comment: What is this filePath?  You can not control external process to get files or folders details. InterOp can help to show the dialog but this not much manageable and easy task..

Comment: I edit question! Could you please check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to go through below reference links:
[Extend OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog the easy way](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19566/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-the-easy)
[OpenFileDialog file sorting](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?443285-OpenFileDialog-file-sorting)

> **If you want to do in OpenFileDialog then you have to create a custom dialog and then use the Win32 API calls to modify default behavior of
>   the dialog.**

[How to Open a Directory Sorted by Date?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5a6c0d72-7a2c-4e55-bf40-c1fe9549f354/how-to-open-a-directory-sorted-by-date?forum=netfxbcl) -- This is another possible pragmatically possible way which @Parrish Husband suggested:

```
 DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Windows");
 FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
 Array.Sort(files, (x, y) => x.LastWriteTimeUtc.CompareTo(y.LastWriteTimeUtc));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work for showing the files in order.

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(filePath)
var files = dirInfo.EnumerateFiles(filePath).OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime);
```

However simply opening an explorer window is probably not what you're aiming for.  Are you wanting the user/player to select certain files?

Comment: Thank you. But, I just open certain folder when I click the button!